# Summarize values from a raster brick by latitude bands in R

Tags: raster, r, zonal-statistics

I would like to sumarize (sum and/or mean) values from layers on a raster brick based on latitude bands (been using raster package). Been looking at the package documentation and didn't find a way to do it. Can anyone give any advice on how to do it?

I guess one option would be to use extract by spatial polygons? Or is there a way to do it with another raster where the values would be classes of the latitudes of cells?

Comment: Your question is very similar to this one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49176/how-to-extract-values-from-a-raster-according-to-lat-and-long-of-the-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second option may be straightforward. You can use the 'init' and 'zonal' functions for that

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
values(r) <-1:ncell(r)
zones <- init(r, v='y')
z <- zonal(r, zones, 'mean')
plot(z)
```

If the raster do not align (and you cannot fix that via aggregation) you could also use extract with polygons. E.g.:

```
a <- aggregate(zones, 10, mean)
p <- rasterToPolygons(a, dissolve=TRUE)
e <- extract(r, p, fun=mean)
plot(data.frame(p)[,1], e)
```

Comment: Thanks it was exactly the exactly the "zones <- init(r, v='y')" i was missing. Just as a side note found hovmoller's graph on rasterVis package that does exactly what I wanted to do (without knowing something like that existed). Anyway your answer was very useful.