# Extract values from multiple rasters using lat / long and save as one CSV file

Tags: raster, latitude-longitude, extract

I would like to extract values from multiple rasters with a single lat / long or Shapefile. I have tried every tutorial and stackoverflow post and am getting nowhere. Maybe someone could please help. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
# Imports
library(raster)
library(sp)

# Raster List
tmp <- lapply(list.files("D:/rasters", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE), raster)

# Lat and Lon
coords <- data.frame("lat" = c(29.940668), "lon" = c(48.363455))

# Create spatial points
pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = coords, 
              proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0  "))

# Extract the points
as.data.frame(cbind(coords, do.call("rbind", lapply(tmp, extract, pts))))
```

The code runs but the return values are all NA and I checked and I should be getting back some values.

I have also tried to read the values in as a shapefile using readOGR as in [Extracting values from raster according to Lat and long of values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49176), but I get an error

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
>     Cannot open layer

I'm at a loss why nothing is working for me.

Comment: What spatial reference does your raster(s) have? You may need to project your points.

Comment: Thanks, I am guessing you are asking regarding the readOGR issue. Both are in Geographic Coordinate systems - GCS WGS1984. Should both file types be projected?

Comment: No, projected or geographic shouldn't matter so long as they are both the same.

Comment: Can you confirm that Iraq is your area of interest (or, at least, this point should be in Iraq)?

Comment: Yep - it's actually Kuwait that I want. I have 3 lat/lon places. I'm thinking to extract the values one location at a time and then aggregate the files later.

Comment: You're not gonna believe this...or maybe you will. The first attempt worked when I switched the lat/lon values. Eeek. I do not think using the "lat" and "lon" definers actually did anything. I think the correct ordering is lon, lat fpr the data.frame. Does this make sense?

Comment: Honestly, I don't use R whatsoever, so I don't know about the definers. But, I do know that switching up lat/lon or missing a negative in the coords are some of the most common problems on this forum. :)

Comment: According to this question, lat/lon should not be in quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181715/how-to-make-a-data-frame-into-a-simple-features-data-frame/52951856#52951856

Comment: Thanks ^^ maybe it's the quotes that negate the definer and it defaults to the lon/lat ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all! I finally got it working per the code below.

```
# Imports
library(raster)
library(sp)

# Raster List
tmp <- lapply(list.files("D:/rasters", pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE), raster)

# Lon and lat without quotes per phloem's comment above  
coords <- data.frame(lon = 47.667, lat = 29.317)

# Create spatial points
pts <- SpatialPoints(coords = coords, 
              proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0  "))

# Extract the points
result <- as.data.frame(cbind(coords, do.call("rbind", lapply(tmp, extract, pts))))

# Write to csv file
write.csv(result, file="filename.csv")
```

I was also able to finally read in the shapefile too but abandoned that method since the first one finally worked. Nonetheless, here is the code that finally worked to read in the shapefile:

```
point_location <- readOGR("foldername","shapefile name without extension")
```

Thanks again!